# How to create an editable directory in Android

Tags: android, listactivity

I want to create a new *activity* called "Custom Directory". That *activity* will have a heading called "Directory"
With the following list format:

> Name Number
>
> Name Number
>
> Name Number

And at last a `button` called "Add new.." Where we can add more of such names/numbers. 
Also on long pressing any item, a `context menu` will come called *Edit/Delete*.

How do I go about doing this? With file writing and stuff, to save the data to sd while the app is inactive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Take one list view and edittext when you enter data into editext stored into "List"(Whatevere container you use i.e `Arraylist.Array`) and this "List" container set into adapter
2. Now give `onlongcliklistener` your listview item for delete and edit

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please detail it a bit, or link me to somewhere? I'm a newbie. I looked in Google's documentation though, but it didn't detail out clearly the process of making this kind of directories, where the data will be saved when the app is closed. Or maybe I'm missing something?